# Html.BeginForm doesn't have onBegin, onComplete methods like Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm working in ASP.NET MVC 5.
I'm showing a loader during a form submit using a Ajax.BeginForm:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Filter", "Log", new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "reloadGrid", OnFailure = "notifyError", HttpMethod = "POST", LoadingElementId = "myModalLoader", OnBegin= "showLoader();", OnComplete = "hideLoader();" }, new { @id = "filter-form" }))
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in another web page where I've a Html.BeginForm:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm( "Index", "GestioneImmagini", FormMethod.Get, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET",  LoadingElementId = "myModalLoader", OnBegin = "showLoader();", OnComplete = "hideLoader();" }))
```

But onBegin and OnComplete don't fire.

Do you know the reason? Can I use AjaxOptions in Html.BeginForm?

Thanks

Simone

Comment: No. Its not ajax!

Comment: There is no such method of OnComplete for Html.BeginForm

Answer (score 3):

No you can't do it with `Html.BeginForm`.

The reason why you can not is that `Html.BeginForm` renders as `<form>` tag and when you pressing `submit` button this results in synchronous request to server.

If you actually want to do something on request complete you can do it on server side inside controller. Something like redirect or just replace page view.

Anyway if you want to do something with part of the page you should use `Ajax.BeginForm` instead of `Html.BeginForm`